# Dispatching a call upon complete of another in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services, publish-subscribe, angular2-directives

I have a scenario where I want to delete an item from a list, and then refresh the page to show the list implying that the item was indeed deleted from the list.

Below is my code for the same.
The DELETE_APPLICATION deletes the application currently, and GET_INSIGHT_APPLICATIONS gets the list of application. However, since it is happening too soon, one after the other, the list also shows the application that was deleted. If I refresh the page(which calls GET_INSIGHT_APPLICATIONS), the list correctly removes the item from the list.

```
handleDeleteApplication(applicationName: string, versionNumber: string, biEngine: string): void {
        console.log('came inside the handleDeleteApplication application, engine =='+biEngine);
        this.store.dispatch({ type: DELETE_APPLICATION, payload: { applicationName : applicationName, applicationEngine : biEngine, versionNumber : versionNumber } });
        console.log('done with dispatch');

        console.log('about to call GET_INSIGHT_APPLICATIONS');
        (this.store.dispatch({ type: GET_INSIGHT_APPLICATIONS }));
        console.log('done with GET_INSIGHT_APPLICATIONS');
    }
```

I was told to subscribe for the completion of the first event. However, I haven't been able to figure out how I can perform that. Kindly suggest an example.

Answer (score 0):

What you would need in this case is to subscribe to the `delete` and when it completes to reload you data.

Example:

```
this.myService.delete(id)
  subscribe(result => {
    if(result.isSuccess){
      this.myService.getItems()
        .subscribe(items => {
          this.items = items;
        });
    }
});
```